# Learning OOP: Overloading the + or = operator error

Tags: c++, oop

I thought I would edit this for anyone else that sees it. I have fixed it thanks to the answers of you guys. The error was because of having the delete pointer in both the constructors for some stupid reason lol. Removed them both and it compiles fine :D

Hi I have been working extensively the past few days learning more on classes and operator overloading, copy constructors etc. using Ivor Hortons visual C++ 2012.

I have created a class previously with the same concept but this time I tried to make the code clearer with output showing which objects are created when and what happens whenever, pretty much just experimenting getting used to the flow of execution and what not.

Now in this class that I made, I keep getting an access violation after adding the operator overload for "+" and "=" in my class. I have looked at previous classes I have wrote and cannot see how I have done it any different this time. This is my code I have been working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:
static int countObj;

explicit Game(char* title = "Default title", int difficulty = 10, int players = 4)
{
    delete [] mp_title;
    mp_title = new char[strlen(title) + 1];
    strcpy_s(mp_title, strlen(title) + 1, title);
    m_difficulty = difficulty;
    m_players = players;
    m_objID = countObj;
    cout << "Object " << ++countObj << " created" << endl;
}

Game(const Game& objGame)
{
    delete [] mp_title;
    mp_title = new char[strlen(objGame.mp_title) + 1];
    strcpy_s(mp_title, strlen(objGame.mp_title) + 1, objGame.mp_title);
    m_difficulty = objGame.m_difficulty;
    m_players = objGame.m_players;
    cout << "Object " << ++countObj << " created using copy constructor" << endl;
    m_objID = countObj;

}

~Game()
{
    cout << "Destructor called on object: " << this->getObjID() << endl;
    delete [] mp_title;
}

Game operator=(const Game&& objGame)
{
    cout << "= operator used as rh expression on object: " << this->getObjID() << endl;
    delete [] mp_title;
    mp_title = new char[strlen(objGame.mp_title) + 1];
    strcpy_s(this->mp_title, strlen(objGame.mp_title) + 1, objGame.mp_title);

    return *this;
}

Game& operator=(const Game& objGame)
{
    if (this != &objGame)
    {
        cout << "= operator called on object " << this->getObjID() << endl;
        delete [] mp_title;
        size_t len = strlen(objGame.mp_title) + 1;
        mp_title = new char[len];
        strcpy_s(mp_title, len, objGame.mp_title);
        m_difficulty = objGame.m_difficulty;
        m_players = objGame.m_players;
    }

    return *this;
}

Game operator+(const Game& objGame) const 
{
    cout << "+ called" << endl;
    return Game("Default title",
                (m_difficulty + objGame.m_difficulty),
                (m_players + objGame.m_players) );
} 

char* getTitle() { return mp_title; }
void setTitle(char* title) { mp_title = title; }
int getObjID() { return m_objID; }

private:
char* mp_title;
int m_difficulty;
int m_players;
int m_objID;
};

int Game::countObj = 0;

int main()
{

Game game1("Game 1", 10, 4);
Game game2("Game 2", 5, 2);
Game game3 = game2;

game2.operator=(game3.operator+(game1));

cout << game1.getObjID() << endl << game2.getObjID() << endl;
cout << game1.getTitle() << endl << game2.getTitle() << endl;

return 0;
```

}

So as I said, it is something to do with the:

```
game2 = game3 + game1;
```

Because when that is removed the program runs.
I would also like some feedback on any coding styles and conventions that I could use in my code. Thanks in advance.

The error I get in the debugger is: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCC0

Comment: why are you using `char*` for strings in c++? Use `std::string`. Btw there are some issues with your code, and it will appropriate to post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was using std::string in my classes. The book I am reading just used a pointer to char in the examples to show how to deal with pointers in a class so I just followed suit, but yes I do prefer std::string. And thanks for the link, I will check it out.

Comment: Why the `delete [] mp_title` in the constructors?

Comment: It is good to know how pointers work. But I would learn each one separately.

Comment: Good question lol. I now see why that isn't necessary. Thank you. Still something not right with the game2 = game3 + game1 though :(

Comment: What do you mean Nyobe? I had my code working with a pointer to a string instead of char before, then re wrote it with a char like the book, just to get a feel of using char as well, but I seem to misunderstand something with the operator overloading (i think)

Comment: Don't overload those operators. It's confusing. You think you need to do it, but you don't.

Comment: Just doing it for learning purposes, I am sure I will need them down the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete [] mp_title;
```

This deletes the at that point completely uninitialized pointer mp_title. You never need this in the constructor (as everything is by definition uninitialized). This goes for both constructors, but no others.

As a generic hint, C0000005 is a segmentation fault (access of some kind of memory that isn't allocated, and addresses starting with CCCCC or CDCDCD are Visual Studio's default debug filler for uninitialized memory.

```
Game operator=(const Game&& objGame)
```

This one can just swap the current and the other's contents; you're guaranteed that the argument will be destructed next so you can use that as your "waste disposal". No need to make a copy, just swap.

```
    size_t len = strlen(objGame.mp_title) + 1;
    mp_title = new char[len];
    strcpy_s(mp_title, len, objGame.mp_title);
```

This is a Microsoft-ism. strcpy_s is not quite as portable as strcpy (1) and in this case, you're passing strlen(arg3) as length anyway, making it not a hair safer than just using strcpy (2). Get used to using just strcpy and find out when it is unsafe; that will help you prevent more bugs than blanket use of strcpy_s without knowing what bugs you're trying to prevent.

Just tried running it on Gcc 4.7.3 (default Ubuntu 13.04 compiler) and after removing said two deletes from the constructors, it runs fine. Result is

```
Object 1 created
Object 2 created
Object 3 created using copy constructor
+ called
Object 4 created
= operator used as rh expression on object: 1
Object 5 created using copy constructor
Destructor called on object: 5
Destructor called on object: 3
0
1
Game 1
Default title
Destructor called on object: 3
Destructor called on object: 1
Destructor called on object: 0
```

Which looks a bit wrong (especially the object IDs), but it doesn't crash.

Your setTitle is very wrong (doesn't copy its argument) but you're not using it so that's not causing trouble now.

And as people have mentioned before, you should be using std::strings as they prevent exactly this kind of messups. In fact, if you used those you could probably remove most of the constructors & destructors and let the default-generated ones do the work for you.

Comment: Move-assignment should not take a `const` parameter, otherwise the argument is un-movable. You need `Game operator=(Game&& objGame)`.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, Still no effect on the access violation though. I know it has something to do with the pointer in the class but I am stumped as to why.

Comment: Your `delete [] mp_title` causes undefined behaviour because `mp_title` was not allocated with `new[]` . It is a likely culprit for an access violation. You must only `delete[]` things that were allocated with `new[]`.  In fact you should remove all manual memory management from your code, and use a container such as `std::string` instead. That way, you ensure in one fell swoop that your code has no memory errors, and your program becomes simpler and thus easier to work on and understand.

Comment: Yes I removed the delete call from the constructor, no idea why I put that there. That however, doesnt fix the access violation. I would and have used string, even a pointer to a string, but for learning purposes I am trying it with char* as well. I might re write this code from scratch and see how I go now after receiving feedback from you guys though. I would still love to know where this memory violation is though lol.

Comment: Yes @dascandy that was the solution! Now I will look over why I put that and why I shouldnt put it their. Thanks!!! And just relooked at it and realise how dumb I am... deleteing a non existant pointer. I was looking in the wrong place lol, I swear it was in the operator overloading. Lesson learned. Again thank you!

Comment: And you say I should only use std::str. So is using a char* [] pretty much pointless now? Because the book I am reading uses char extensively instead of string at the moment, but the goes into string later on. And this book is from 2012 so I thought that char must be used quite a bit in the real world, hence why I wanted to make sure I knew how to use it

Comment: It's not pointless; there are cases where it is better to use char arrays or char *'s. These are limited to some inner loops (and if you have strings in your inner loops, start asking yourself some major questions) and input handling. Nearly all cases with strings are not performance sensitive and in those cases it's always better to use std::string as it is much harder to mess it up.